# C: stdout hangs linux pipes

Tags: c, linux, bash, pipe

I've written a simple I/O echoing program in C to test a problem with a bigger real program. Here, linux FD redirection doesn't work.

The echoing program (aka `a.out`) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char buff[10];
  while (1) {
    if (fgets(buff, 10, stdin) == NULL) break;
    printf("PRINT: %s \n", buff);
  }
}
```

From Bash, I run it as:

```
$ mkfifo IN OUT
$ # this is a method to keep the pipes IN and OUT opened over time
$ while :; do read; echo Read: $REPLY >&2; sleep 1; done <OUT >IN &
$ a.out >OUT <IN &

$ echo xyz >IN
```

and there is no output produced: the Bash `while` loop isn't able to read from `OUT`.

---

Let's compare this a.out with `cat`, which instead works as expected:

```
$ mkfifo IN OUT
$ while :; do read; echo Read: $REPLY >&2; sleep 1; done <OUT >IN &
$ cat >OUT <IN &

$ echo xyz >IN
Read: xyz
```

This last line is printed on console to stderr.
`cat`'s output, differently from a.out's, is able to travel across `OUT` and reach the Bash `while` loop, which then prints it on console.

What's wrong with a.out?

Comment: I've always used linux pipes (in Bash) with multiple sources. The data is randomly multiplexed. Even multiple destinations are possible for one single pipe, but here the behaviour is unpredictable.

Comment: Actually, never mind, what I said makes no sense!

Comment: If I am not wrong, after redirecting `stdout` to the pipe, the IO stream will not be line-buffered but fully-buffered. You could also use `setbuf` to change it to line-buffered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to add `fflush(stdout)` after `printf(...)`.

Comment: I added the fflush(stdout), but it still works exactly as the former a.out. (excuse me for the edits)

Comment: Works for me with an fflush(stdout) added (or by simply overwhelming the buffer, i.e. seq 1 1000 > IN )

Comment: Wow, fflush() actually solves the problem. This is my fault to be too busy an little focused. And with it, I also fixed the bigger, real program!